# WebStorm default settings, environment variables are not getting copied

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm

My understanding is that under default settings for Mocha in WebStorm and any environment variables should be copied to other Mocha tests that I create but they are not.

See the image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes -- that's how it should be doing. Just note -- such copying occurs only when you create new Run/Debug configuration of that type (Mocha in your case). Editing default entry does not affect already created entries in any way.

Comment: I see, so the problem was I was changing default settings after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct -- that's exactly how it works.

The only note: such copying only occurs when you create **new** Run/Debug configuration of that type (Mocha in your case). *Editing Default entry does not affect already created entries (of that type) in any way*.